# Lyx: How to install the IOP document class

Tags: latex, lyx

I am using Lyx to write a report. I would like to write this report using the IOP (Institute of Physics) document class.

When I select this document class, Lyx informs me that some files have not been installed:

The selected document class
    article (IOP)
requires external files that are not available.
The document class can still be used, but the
document cannot be compiled until the following
prerequisites are installed:
    iopart.cls
    iopams.sty
    setstack.sty
See section 3.1.2.2 (Class Availability) of the
User's Guide for more information.

I have read through this section but it hasn't enabled me to fix the problem.

I have downloaded the Latex style files etc from here: http://authors.iop.org/atom/help.nsf/0/B042B0AF79C815B88025702000409514?OpenDocument

But I don't know how to go about installing them for my latex compiler and then I don't know how to tell Lyx that they are now available on my system.

How do I do these 2 things?

Comment: Does it work if you put the style files in the same folder as your lyx document?

Comment: Unfortunately not - Lyx doesn't know about the files

Comment: Can you compile the tex file that comes with the IOP style files (without Lyx)? Perhaps you need to put the style files in the system or user directory of your tex distribution (the exact paths depend on the OS and the particular distribution) in order for Lyx to see them.

Comment: Installing has to do with your LaTeX distribution (TeX Live/ MiKTeX). Follow those instructions. Then in LyX do Tools > Reconfigure.